# Parity on the number of rooted trees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, planar-graphs

Suppose we have a planar graph with vertices $v_0, \ldots, v_n$, where $n$ is even such that there exist a checkerboard coloring of the regions in the complement such that the black regions are $n$ (non-degerate) triangular faces having clockwise orientation.

Prove that the number of oriented rooted spanning trees, say oriented from the root $v_0$, is an odd number. (An *oriented spanning tree* rooted at $v$ is an acyclic subgraph in which every vertex other than $v$ has indegree $1$.)

In attached example:

[image]

I counted $11$ trees, and my strategy was to put the trees in pairs, but it gets complicated like in the example where we have two the edges from $v_1$ to $v_2$.

Comment: The relationship between oriented spanning trees and Eulerian tours (see, e.g., [Theorem 13 in these notes](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~levine/18.312/alg-comb-lecture-20.pdf)) might be relevant, but I don't know how.

Comment: (A nice consequence of that theorem is that the number of oriented spanning trees rooted at $v_i$ is the same for all $i$; since $n+1$, the number of vertices, is odd, it's enough to show that the total number of oriented spanning trees regardless of root is odd.)

Comment: What if your graph complement doesn't have a "checkerboard coloring"?  For example, a square, plus a vertex $v_0$ with edges attached to the corners.  Then $n$ is even.  Do you want to assume that you have such a coloring of the complement?

Comment: Yes, I am assuming existence of checkerboard coloring, and that all triangular faces have distinct three vertices.

Comment: I made and then rolled back an edit to the Question, to clarify what is being colored in your first mention of checkerboard-coloring.  Perhaps you could review my attempt and then make such an edit yourself, as the wording currently suggests that there might be two kinds of colorings involved.

Comment: You might have already noticed that, but your checkboard colouring suggests some kind of "onion peeling", meaning that if remove the edge and degree 1 or 2 vertices that boards the outer-region (in white) then you get a new smaller graph with again a checkerboard colouring. This suggest some kind of induction. The edges/vertices you remove form a cycle. Now you might have a graph with an even number of vertices (in your example $v_0$ would be removed), so we have to see if such graphs have an even number of oriented rooted trees ($C_2$ and $C_4$ seems to).

Comment: Without the vertex $v_0$ and adjacent triangle in the example, the number of rooted trees is $7$ which is not even.

Comment: Oh too bad. Although what I was suggesting is to remove also the black triangle $v_1,v_2,v_3$, which leaves you with 2 black triangles $v_0v_2v_4$ and $v_0v_3v_4$ (I was thinking this should be removed as you cannot continue to do a "peeling" just by removing vertices of degree $2$, and I wanted to find some kind of induction). You end up with 2 rooted spanning trees, but another issue arises: you now have way more vertices than black triangles.